# Deleting or hiding individual requests from Firefox's Network tab (Developer tools)

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In the Network tab of Firefox's Developer tools, I've enabled the display of only XHR requests (because I just want to follow AJAX calls and responses), and nothing else.

Since a webapp I'm monitoring has various periodic background checks (in the intervals of 5-10 seconds), the Network display gets clogged up in a very short period of time.

Is it possible to clear the list of specific requests, in any way (for example, deleting from the list those requests that are of no immediate interest to me)?

If that's not possible, is it possible to set a negative filter of a sort? By that I mean - if the URL XHR target is `example.com/checker?notification=lorem&type=ipsum`, don't display it, and if it's anything else, display it.

Clicking on specific XHR requests, and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> does nothing. Right clicking opens up the context menu, but there's no Delete option, or the option to hide requests targeting this specific URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/index.html), all I had to do is to prefix a specific substring with `-`, in order to hide it from the list of network requests.

Comment: I had no idea that you could also filter by properties - https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/index.html#filtering-by-properties